# How to downsample a python list having time

Tags: python, arrays, database, list, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-dimensional list in python that contains the X and Y coordinates of a graph.
**Like this:**

```
list1 = [[12345678, 12345678], [12345678, 12345678], [12345678, 12345678]]
```

The First element of every inner list is X axis and the second is Y axis. All the X axis elements are [epoch (Unix timestamp)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and I want to somehow reduce the number of elements in this list by only keeping the timestamps after some set interval say 5 minutes. So, any points that are between say 1:00 pm and 1:05 pm should be removed...

So, how can that be done in the most efficient way

Comment: You can also recommend me a library that can downsample the data close enough so that I don't need to skip that data every 5 minutes.... (if possible)

Comment: You'll need a start time and an end time (start time + interval). Sort the 2d list. Iterate over the list looking for the first element that is greater than or equal to the start time. Make a note of where that is (index). Continue iteration until you get to an element whose value is greater than the end time. Note the index. Slice the original array based on the two indices you've identified. If the list is extremely long, you may want to implement a binary chop to establish a better starting point than index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood what you what, then this example of code may help you.

```
import datetime
input_data = [[12345678, 12345678], [12346678, 12345678], [12346698, 12345678], [12446678, 12345678], [12455678, 12345678]]

# If you're sure that the input data is always sorted so you can skip this line input_data.sort(key=lambda x : x[0])

result = [input_data[0]] 
for i in range(1, len(input_data)):
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(input_data[i][0])
    previous_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(result[-1][0])
    
    # 5 minutes = 5 * 60 = 300 seconds (you can change this to any time interval)
    if (date - previous_date).total_seconds() > 300 :
        result.append(input_data[i])
```

So as I mentioned above if you're list is already sorted so you can skip the sort line.

So what going on here :
First we copy the first item
Then we go to the next item in the input list, we first check the time difference. If the difference is less than 5 minutes we will ignore the item otherwise we will append it to the result list. And so on.

I hope this is helpful otherwise you can tell me if I miss understood your question.

---

PS: based on the comment below, here is how the code looks like if you use enumerate rather than the range :

```
result = [input_data[0]]
for _, date_i in enumerate(input_data):
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date_i[0])
    previous_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(result[-1][0])

    # 5 minutes = 5 * 60 = 300 seconds (you can change this to any time interval)
    if (date - previous_date).total_seconds() > 300:
        result.append(date_i)
```

Comment: @kauother I just read some days ago that in Python, instead of using for loop with range(1,len(x)) it's more pythonic to use enumrate(list), this way you can access the index and the data.

Comment: @AlejandroA thank you so much, nice to know. 

I updated the answer based on you suggestion 

Comment: @kauother no problem! Glad to help and thanks for helping the person who posted this! let's learn all together :)